# VB.Net - JSON - If, ElseIf

Tags: json, vb.net

**My JSON**

```
{

"name": "username",
"status": "mystatus",
"quality": "5",
"place": {
"name": "placename",
}
```

Currently i am defining the color like:

```
picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Magenta
```

I would like to change the `BackColor` depending on the number returned by quality,i'm not sure how to do the multiple if's

```
colors:-
0 = Gray
1 = White
2 = Green
3 = Blue
4 = Magenta
5 = Orange
6 = Beige
7 = Beige
```

I currently retrieve my json string like this for a text box

```
placename.Text = jResults2("place")("name").ToString()
```

So i think it would be like

```
picturebox1.BackColor = jResults2("status") Is "0", "Color.Gray,
```

i'm just not sure how to proceed

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better for you to use the select command.

```
 Select Case value
         Case 1
         'CHANGE COLOR
         Case 2
         'CHANGE COLOR
         Case 5
         'CHANGE COLOR
         Case Else
         'CHANGE COLOR
 End Select
```

Because you asked for the code here is the first 5 for you...

```
Dim value = jResults2("place")("name").ToString()
Select Case value
         Case 0
              picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Gray
         Case 1
              picturebox1.BackColor = Color.White
         Case 2
              picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Green
         Case 3
              picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Blue
         Case 4
              picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Magenta
End Select
```

Comment: whats the best way to implement and use this

Comment: what do you mean "best way to implement". `value` would be your quality as an integer. Case 1 means thats `value` = 1 so change your background color.

Comment: what code would i use as this Select is new to me it may be worth mentioning i am rather new to vb Thanks